# Custom ListView using CardView BaseAdapter OnItemClick

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, android-cardview

I really need help and some solution

I try to make a custom `ListView` using `CardView` with `BaseAdapter`, I have 5 list of item. Every list contains an image, tittle and description.
I got some problem, I didn't know how to use Click every `ListView` into different new activity

**This is the baseAdapter java code**

```js
package com.projectskripsi.wisatajogja.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.projectskripsi.wisatajogja.R;
import com.projectskripsi.wisatajogja.model.Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class WisataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Model> models;

    public WisataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> models) {
        this.context = context;
        this.models = models;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return models.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){

            convertView = View.inflate(context , R.layout.list_item1 ,null);
        }
        ImageView images = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wisataimage);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namawisataTV);
        TextView about = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wisatadesTV);

        Model model = models.get(position);

        images.setImageResource(model.getWisataimage());
        title.setText(model.getWisataTitle());
        about.setText(model.getAboutTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**and This Model java**

```js
package com.projectskripsi.wisatajogja.model;




public class Model {

    private int wisataimage;
    private String wisataTitle;
    private String aboutTitle;

    public Model(int wisataimage, String wisataTitle, String aboutTitle) {
        this.wisataimage = wisataimage;
        this.wisataTitle = wisataTitle;
        this.aboutTitle = aboutTitle;
    }

    public int getWisataimage() {
        return wisataimage;
    }

    public void setWisataimage(int wisataimage) {
        this.wisataimage = wisataimage;
    }

    public String getWisataTitle() {
        return wisataTitle;
    }

    public void setWisataTitle(String wisataTitle) {
        this.wisataTitle = wisataTitle;
    }

    public String getAboutTitle() {
        return aboutTitle;
    }

    public void setAboutTitle(String aboutTitle) {
        this.aboutTitle = aboutTitle;
    }
}
```

**And This MainActivity Java**

```js
package com.projectskripsi.wisatajogja;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.projectskripsi.wisatajogja.adapter.WisataAdapter;
import com.projectskripsi.wisatajogja.model.ListDetails1;
import com.projectskripsi.wisatajogja.model.Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GunungKidul extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Model> models;
    private WisataAdapter wisataAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gunung_kidul);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listwisata1);
        models = ListDetails1.getList();

        wisataAdapter = new WisataAdapter(GunungKidul.this,models);
        listView.setAdapter(wisataAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Model model = models.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(GunungKidul.this, Pantai_Kesirat.class);
                intent.putExtra("wisataTittle", listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                startActivity(intent);




            }
        });

    }
}
```

Thankyou for your answer.. i really need help guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Model model= (Model) wisataAdapter.getItem(position);

                if(position==0){
                   Intent intent = new Intent(GunungKidul.this, Pantai_Kesirat.class);
                   //To pass whole model data with intent:
                   intent.putExtra("MyClassKey", model);
                   startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GunungKidul.this,  Goa_Pindul.class);
                    //To pass whole model data with intent:
                    intent.putExtra("MyClassKey", model);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
        else if{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GunungKidul.this, Pantai_Baron.class);
                    //To pass whole model data with intent:
                    intent.putExtra("MyClassKey", model);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
        else if{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GunungKidul.this, Goa_Jomblang.class);
                    //To pass whole model data with intent:
                    intent.putExtra("MyClassKey", model);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
        else if{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GunungKidul.this, AirTerjun.class);
                    //To pass whole model data with intent:
                    intent.putExtra("MyClassKey", model);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }



                            }
                        })

;
```

use this code But always remember your card position or index value and which activity should open when clicked cardViewlike if u click First cardView open Pantai_Kesirat activity

Comment: why models.get(position)); //position become red?

Comment: I have done some modification please look at this and try

Answer (score 0):

Use Serializable in your model class like this:

```
package com.projectskripsi.wisatajogja.model;

    public class Model implements Serializable {

        private int wisataimage;
        private String wisataTitle;
        private String aboutTitle;

        public Model(int wisataimage, String wisataTitle, String aboutTitle) {
            this.wisataimage = wisataimage;
            this.wisataTitle = wisataTitle;
            this.aboutTitle = aboutTitle;
        }

        public int getWisataimage() {
            return wisataimage;
        }

        public void setWisataimage(int wisataimage) {
            this.wisataimage = wisataimage;
        }

        public String getWisataTitle() {
            return wisataTitle;
        }

        public void setWisataTitle(String wisataTitle) {
            this.wisataTitle = wisataTitle;
        }

        public String getAboutTitle() {
            return aboutTitle;
        }

        public void setAboutTitle(String aboutTitle) {
            this.aboutTitle = aboutTitle;
        }
    }
```

then your First activity from you pass the data to another activity on listview item click event is write like as:

```
public class GunungKidul extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Model> models;
    private WisataAdapter wisataAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gunung_kidul);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listwisata1);
        models = ListDetails1.getList();

        wisataAdapter = new WisataAdapter(GunungKidul.this,models);
        listView.setAdapter(wisataAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(GunungKidul.this, Pantai_Kesirat.class);
              //To pass whole model data with intent:
             intent.putExtra("MyClassKey", models.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);




            }
        });

    }
}
```

Now In Pantai_Kesirat class you have make a model class Object like:

```
Model model;
```

then in `onCreate()` method of your second Activity, just recieve your data from intent like:

```
    // To retrieve object in second Activity
   model =(Model) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClassKey");
```

then use data of your model class where u want with help of getter and setter method of your model class

Comment: can you explain more? i have 5 Cardview in ListView..and i want in 5 cardview can open each activity..

Comment: each cardview open in same activity where data will be changed??

Comment: when u click any cardview then open a activity Pantai_Kesirat as u mention in intent then clicked 's all details available in Pantai_Kesirat activity  and as per as your requirement u can set data into different view

Comment: can u give me the code? i have..Pantai_Kesirat activity, Goa_Pindul activity, Pantai_Baron activity, Goa_Jomblang Activity AirTerjun activity.. and i want the 5 cardview open each activity.. cardview have same name for the activity

Comment: sure,just add if  and else if condtion in onItemClick() method  like this:
but u have mut know the which postition of cartView open which activity

Comment: i confused read your comment in here @@ im so sorry bro.. i can't understand

Comment: And change Intent with if else if condition like that:
if(position==0){
 Intent intent = new Intent(GunungKidul.this, Pantai_Kesirat.class);
              //To pass whole model data with intent:
             intent.putExtra("MyClassKey", models.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
}
else if(position==1){
 Intent intent = new Intent(GunungKidul.this, Goa_Pindul.class);
              //To pass whole model data with intent:
             intent.putExtra("MyClassKey", models.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
}

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

So I have a simple solution to your defined problem, check that if it works for you.

1. You implement a click listener, say "CardClickListener" in your MainActivity (the one that has a list of CardViews).
2. Pass **this** while initiating the Adapter for the ListView.
3. In your Adapter, on every click to CardItem, you call this clickListener and pass the data object associated it to the MainActivity.
4. Parse the data object in your MainActivity and based on that go to your respective activity.

While this solution will work for sure, I'm not convinced that this is the best solution to your problem. Once you have something working, try to improve this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you explain with the code what i share on my post?